# Replacing lines in text files (lasts) bash

Tags: bash, sed

I have three following lines inside textfile (last 3 lines):

```
         } 
    } 
  }
```

What I would like to do is do something like this:

```
         } 
     } 
blablabla
blablabla
blablabla
  }
```

Is there any way to do it with `sed` or any other command without putting specific line number?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As it's almost the last line, you could go for a solution using awk:

```
awk '{ print p; p = $0 }END{ print "blablabla\nblablabla\nblablabla"; print p }' file
```

This buffers each line in the variable `p`, printing the previous one. At the end of the file, print the lines you want to insert, before printing the last line.

As usual, to redirect the output to a file, use redirection and to do an "in-place" edit, use a temporary file:

```
for file in *; do
    awk '...' "$file" > tmp && mv tmp "$file"
done
```

Comment: clever one, well done! A more robust check would keep a counter of how many times `}` appeared and print `blabla` just if it is 2.

Comment: Thanks! Yeah, I guess it depends on what else there is in the file though.

Comment: I've tried both of the solutions (yours and the one above) and unfortunately result is the same. It shows me text file of the screen (it looks like I want it to) but in file there is no change. Could you help me with that? I want to make this process recursively for all files in folder so I'm using `for` command. (not sure if in this case it matters) Thanks once again!

Comment: @nemox007 please see my edit, which shows how to overwrite the input file.

Comment: Awesome. Looks like it works. Is there any reason why does it not work for a first time? Thanks a lot for help!

Comment: @nemox007 it is the default behaviour of most shell tools to write their output to standard output (i.e. the terminal), unless you explicitly redirect it to a file.

Answer (score 5):

with GNU sed

```
sed -i '$i blablabla\nblablabla\nblablabla' file
```

$ is matching last line, but i is insert which puts text before matched line

Use `-i` option to `sed` to perform the operations in-place, in this case modifying the info it file.